# Spring batch & Spring batch Admin Project

Tags: spring-batch, jettison

We have a project with Spring Batch & Spring Batch Admin.
Recently we got `java.util.EmptyStackException` while running the batch process.

After googling I got some idea of the problem and resolved it by upgrading the jettison jar from 1.1 to 1.3.2.

We did this by excluding the jettison in the spring batch core declaration in **pom.xml** and adding jettison as a dependency in the **pom.xml**.

The question we have is Is this the right way to resolve this issue?
Will there be any issue with Spring Batch because of upgrading jettison to 1.3.2?

The stack trace of the error we were getting:

```
Caused by: java.util.EmptyStackException
    at org.codehaus.jettison.util.FastStack.peek(FastStack.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement(MappedXMLStreamWriter.java:200)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxWriter.endNode(StaxWriter.java:107)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.WriterWrapper.endNode(WriterWrapper.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.path.PathTrackingWriter.endNode(PathTrackingWriter.java:48)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:138)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:113)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:95)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.marshal(MapConverter.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:845)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:834)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:815)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:805)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.serialize(XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:43)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.serializeContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:212)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:122)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy61.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer in the question :) I would recommend opening a jira ticket https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently come across this. I'm not sure if you have the full stacktrace there but in my app there was a call to:

```
sun.misc.Unsafe
```

There was a change in 2016 that broke a number of jvm langs like groovy. The jettison 1.1 is clearly not using this 'Unsafe' call which may change in JVM versions(it's not part of the normal java API's)